# Code is not getting executed when I include this class PHP

Tags: php, oop

I took good care to create this class but I am not sure what is wrong with it. The code runs perfectly if I don't have any content inside,

```
class TemplateOne{

}
```

But once I run this code it breaks,

```
<?php

class TemplateOne {

    //Properties
    protected $_bgColor;
    protected $_logoImagePath;
    protected $_headerText;
    protected $_leftContentHeader;
    protected $_rightContentHeader;
    protected $_leftContentBody;
    protected $_rightContentBody;
    protected $_footer;
    protected $_mediaIframe;
    protected $_mediaHeight = '';
    protected $_mediaWidth = '';

    //DB communication
    public $DB;

    //Constructor
    public function __construct(){

        //Connect database in construct and close connection in destruct

        $config = array();

        $config['host'] = 'localhost';
        $config['user'] = 'root';
        $config['pass'] = 'root';
        $config['database'] = 'fanpage_application';

        $this->DB = new DB($config);

        //init variables
        populateDataFromDataBase();
    }

    //Functions
    public function populateDataFromDataBase() {

        //Get bgcolor
        $this->DB->("SELECT backgroundimage FROM template_style_data WHERE styleid='#list_level'");
        $data = $this->DB->Get();
        foreach($data as $key => $value)
        {
            echo $value['backgroundimage'];
        }
    }

    //Getters
    public function getBgColor()
    {
        return $this->_bgColor;
    }

    public function getLogoImagePath()
    {
        return $this->_logoImagePath;
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        return $this->_headerText;
    }

    public function getLeftContentHeader()
    {
        return $this->_leftContentHeader;
    }

    public function getRightContentHeader()
    {
        return $this->_rightContentHeader;
    }

    public function getLeftContentBody()
    {
        return $this->_leftContentBody;
    }

    public function getRightContentBody()
    {
        return $this->_rightContentBody;
    }

    public function getFooter()
    {
        return $this->_footer;
    }

    public function getMediaIframe()
    {
        return $this->_mediaIframe;
    }

    //Setters

    public function setBgColor($bgColor)
    {
         $this->_bgColor = $bgColor;
    }

    public function setLogoImagePath($logoImagePath)
    {
         $this->_logoImagePath = $logoImagePath;
    }

    public function setHeaderText($headerText)
    {
         $this->_headerText = $headerText;
    }

    public function setLeftContentHeader($leftContentHeader)
    {
         $this->_leftContentHeader = $leftContentHeader;
    }

    public function setRightContentHeader($rightContentHeader)
    {
         $this->_rightContentHeader = $rightContentHeader;
    }

    public function setLeftContentBody($leftContentHeader)
    {
         $this->_leftContentBody = $leftContentHeader;
    }

    public function setRightContentBody($rightContentBody)
    {
         $this->_rightContentBody = $rightContentBody;
    }

    public function setFooter($footer)
    {
         $this->_footer = $footer;
    }

    public function setMediaIframe($mediaIframe)
    {
         $this->_mediaIframe = $mediaIframe;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: So the code breaks? When things do not work, the best solution is to fix the code.

Comment: "The code runs perfectly if I don't have any content inside".  Why yes, code tends to work fine when there's none of it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, Thats true, but I tried hard to find broken but...failed...Sorry if the question is not appropriate...

Comment: @Rocket, Yeah true that was a debugging! I am new to PHP OOP and I already miss those compiler error in JAVA and Objective -C

Comment: @Craftero you can turn on PHP Error Reporting: `ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Do you have a log of it failing or have you turned on display errors  - you should start off working with them until you are more sure that your stuff works. If it is your server (or better still a local vm you have control of), then you should be able to find this in your php.ini file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is the DB class coming from?  You may have to `include` the correct class definition file if it is not already.

```
$this->DB = new DB($config);
```

The following is not legal syntax.  You will need to actually call a function by name.

```
$this->DB->("SELECT backgroundimage FROM template_style_data WHERE styleid='#list_level'");
```

Unless you have another function in the global scope named `populateDataFromDataBase` which is what you want to call, you will need to add `$this->` before you try to call it in your constructor.

```
populateDataFromDataBase();
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing `$this->` from your call to `populateDataFromDataBase`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your error:

```
$this->DB->("SELECT backgroundimage FROM template_style_data WHERE styleid='#list_level'");
```

This is not valid syntax, you need to call a method after `$this->DB`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned there is only one possible answer: check your PHP errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

at least (in devevlopment only, don't show errors in production):

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```